# revolution slider boxed layout, image jumps

Tags: jquery, html, revolution-slider

I have a slider created using revolution slider.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner">
            <ul>
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Intro Slide">
                    <img src="{{url('images/slider-1.jpg')}}" alt="Image 1" />
                </li>
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Product 1 Slide">
                    <img src="{{url('images/slider-2.jpg')}}" alt="Image 2" />
                </li>
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Product 2 Slide">
                    <img src="{{url('images/slider-3.jpg')}}" alt="Image 3" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.tp-banner').revolution({
        startwidth: 1170,
        startheight: 400,
        navigationArrows: "none",
        hideTimerBar:"on",
        fullWidth:"off",
        fullScreen:"off",
        forceFullWidth:"on"
    });
});
```

What I am trying is to create the boxed slider, but it is not going as expected. The image jumps and becomes full screen slider. If I pass the `on` value to the `forceFullWidth` parameter, it works but it becomes a full width slider, I want it to be a boxed slider.

I know this must be a silly mistake, but I am having a hard time to clear this issue.

Kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean this? http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380